# Attempt to bless into a reference while using XML::Twig

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I am using the module XML::Twig for processing XML. While trying to run the `nparse` method with pretty_print option, I get an error. Following is the code:

```
use strict;
use XML::Twig;
use Data::Dumper;

my $xml_string = q{some xml string};
my $twig = XML::Twig->new();

$twig->nparse_pp( pretty_print => 'indented', $xml_string);
```

and the error message:

> Attempt to bless into a reference at local/5.16/lib/perl5/XML/Twig.pm line 463.

Did I miss something?

Comment: what's `$stdout`?

Comment: `nparse_pp` is a class method, not an object method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Did I miss something

- `use strict;` `use warnings;`
- You never actually parse your `$xml_string`
- you never declare or open `$stdout`. (Maybe you mean `STDOUT`)?
- You use both `XML::LibXML` and `XML::Twig`.
- `nparse_pp` implicitly sets `pretty_print => 'indented'` already.

Post some code that actually compiles and runs, and we might be able to help.

But perhaps you want something like;

```
my $twig = XML::Twig -> parse ( $xml_string );
$twig -> set_pretty_print ( 'indented' ); 
$twig -> print;
```

Comment: `XML::Twig->nparse_pp($xml_string)->print;`